Do off-centre forces create additional energy?
When a force is applied to a rigid body at its centre of mass, it accelerates. Over time, that acceleration becomes velocity, which gives the body a certain amount of kinetic energy.
However, if that same force were applied at the edge of that rigid body, perpendicular to the moment arm, it would also impart torque, leading to rotational energy as well as translational motion / kinetic energy.
In the second case (rotational + translational kinetic energy), it seems that more energy is present than in the first case (just translational kinetic energy). Yet, it's the same force, just applied to a different location on the body. How can this be?
I'm sure that I've misunderstood something, so clarification is appreciated!

It is the same force, moved over different distances.

This doesn't answer your question, but it might help - Toppling of a cylinder on a block

If you don't put the force at the CoM, then the translational acceleration isn't as high. You can test this easily - put a plate or a phone or a book or anything on a table, and push at its center vs. at its edge for roughly the same amount of time. In the center case, it moves more forward than in the edge case. The total energy due to rotational and kinetic energy should always sum to the same value, I think.

@controlgroup you are mistaken. The mathematics is very clear.

@naturallyInconsistent what mathematics? Wherever the force is applied you're still expending a constant amount of energy to apply the force over a given time, and the energy has to go somewhere.

@controlgroup that is just more confusion on your part. For a fixed force, the acceleration is the same no matter where it is applied. Energy transfer is force multiplied by distance; what you are saying, force multiplied by time, is momentum transfer. There are many reasons why physicists insist to use mathematics---clarity in such situations is one reason.

@naturallyInconsistent my mistake; even then in concept we agree that the same force is imparting the same total energy to the system?

@controlgroup no, the same force is acting over different distances and so will impart different energies. Instead, the time is the same, so the momentum will be the same. i.e. the translation motion of the CoM will be the exact same.

@naturallyInconsistent that's a bit unintuitive but I guess I can't argue with that, sorry for any confusion anyone. Thank you for explaining

naturallyInconsistent, are you saying that the distance from the CoM that the force is applied means that more work is going into accelerating (linearly & rotationally) the body than if it were applied right at the CoM?

If the line of action of the force is not through the centre of mass then body can be thought of as being acted on by a force whose line of action is through the centre of mass which produces a linear acceleration of the centre of mass and a couple which produces an angular acceleration of the body.
Thus work is done by the applied force displacing the centre of mass of the body and some extra work is done by the force because of the extra displacement due to the rotation of the body.

Where ever the force $F$ acts including at the centre of mass $C$ there is a displacement of the body, $CA$.
If the line of action of the force $F$ is not through the centre of mass the body also rotates about the centre of mass and so the displacement of the body is $BD$.
Because $BD>AB$ the force does more work when the line of action of the force is not hrough the centre of mass.

What "extra work" is being done?

@oak The centre of mass moves, ie the whole rod undergoes a translation but on top of that translation there is a rotation which means a force whose line of action does not go through the centre of mass undergoes an extra translation. Thus the force does more work.

Oh, I see! The force is doing two kinds of work: one by a translational displacement, and the other by a rotational change. Thank you!

There is a standard demonstration in which an  off-centre force is provided by a   string wrapped around a cylinder on a air-table.  Another string  is connected to the c-of-mass of an otherwise identical  cylinder. You pull both  strings with the same force $F$, and see that  the c-of-m's have the same acceleration.  Meanwhile the   string on the wrapped cylinder unwinds and the  torque, $F\times$radius,  makes its cylinder rotate. The unwindng means that you  have move your hand through a much longer distance than for the straight-pull  cylinder,  so the work, $F\times$distance, is larger and provides  the rotational energy.
